# Hiding rows by using a criteria on specific cells is too slow

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I am new to VBA, I have a requirement where I have a sheet of data containing more than 5000 rows. Rows might increase and decrease so it is not a fixed value. Now  I have 20 columns and I have a user input cell where he will enter say in cell `A3`  5 and cell `A5` is 9.

What I need to do is filter row wise, matching values in the range and hide them. The complication is that the matching value has to look on only 5 out of 20 columns. When any one of the cell values matches from the 5 columns, then I should not hide the rows and the rest should be hidden.

example:

```
A          B     C       D        E       F      G       H        I      J
             2014.Jan             2014.FEB                 2014.MAR     
         value1 value2  value3  value1  value2  value3  value1  value2  value3
Material1   5   10      15        20     25     30      35       40     45
Material2   7   8        9        10     11     12      13       14     15
Material3   2   3        4         5     6      7       8        9      10
```

When user enter value  0 to 9.

Then I need to check the columns D,G,J and check if the number falls between 0 to 9. If any one
matches then don't hide the row.

The output should be:

```
A          B     C       D        E       F      G       H        I      J
             2014.Jan             2014.FEB                 2014.MAR     
         value1 value2  value3  value1  value2  value3  value1  value2  value3

Material2   7   8        9        10     11     12      13       14     15
Material3   2   3        4         5     6      7       8        9      10
```

I tried the code below as a sample of the solution but it takes a long time as it loops each field.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next

For Each c In Range("M21:M" & LastRow)
    If c.value >= Range("L10").value And c.value <= Range("N10").value Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I have had some success using built-in filtering and a helper column with formulas to set to TRUE or FALSE when conditions are met.

Comment: Two things: I would set Application.ScreenUpdating = False at the beginning of the code, to avoid refreshing, and Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end. The second tip is to split your if in two parts, one inside the other, in order to avoid unnecessary comparisons.